# How to enable iTerm2's system-wide hotkey when iTem2 is not running

Tags: macos, iterm

For me system-wide hotkey does not work when iTerm2 is closed. Is there a way to enable it? Or maybe create an instance of iTerm that runs invisibly in background and listens for hotkey?

Comment: You could add it as a startup item, but it would open the full UI every time you power on the machine.

Answer (score 6):

Follow these three steps:

1. Launch `Automator` from `/Applications/Utilities`. Create a service for launching iTerm in Automator in these steps:

   1.1. In the first window select `Service` and press `Choose`.

   [image: Automator Create new Service]

   1.2. From left sidebar select `Utilities`. From middle section drag `Launch Application` to the right section and select `iTerm` from the its dropdown list. Select `no input` from upper dropdown list. Save the document by <kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> and provide a meaningful name like `Launch iTerm`.

[image: Launch iTerm workflow]

2. Open `System Preferences` and open `Keyboard` section. Navigate to `Shortcuts` tab. From left sidebar select `Services` and from right list scroll to `General` section. In this section should be an item named `Launch iTerm`. Select it and then click on `add shortcut` button appeared in the right. Assign a shortcut like <kbd>control</kbd>+<kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>.

   [image: Assign Shortcut in Keyboard shortcuts]
3. Open `iTerm` and navigate to the preferences. Assign the same keyboard shortcut in previous section.

   [image: Assign keyboard shortcut in iTerm]

This keyboard shortcut launches iTerm when it is not running and shows/hides iTerm when it is running.

Comment: This is great, the only downside is that it doesn't work for most single-keystroke shortcuts.
This should be the accepted answer, though.

Comment: Works for me, thanks. I use `ctrl+§` for my shortcut. I have never found out what `§` is for, and I don't even want to know.